# Validade if string contains a regex string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string below which was extracted by `DOM Document`:

```
$scripts = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
$script = $scripts->item($i); 
$string = $script->getAttribute('src');// Save the string 'jquery-3.2.0.min.js'
```

I have 3 ways to check if this string is a jquery:

```
jquery(?:\\-|\\.)([\\d.]*\\d)[^/]*\\.js\\;version:\\1
/([\\d.]+)/jquery(?:\\.min)?\\.js\\;version:\\1
jquery.*\\.js
```

In that case how can I validate the above string using one of these 3 commands?

Comment: Do a simple check for "jquery" with `strpos` and check if the node is empty. *(that can also be done with XPath)*. You don't need a regex for that.

Comment: Title and you questions are different.

Comment: I think you're looking for `preg_match()`: http://php.net/preg_match

Comment: Combine all three regexes into one using the pipe character.

Comment: Are each regex supposed to match the entire string? Anyway 3 into 1 is `(?|jquery[-.]([\d.]\d)[^/]\.js;version:\1|/([\d.]+)/jquery(?:\.min)?\.js;version:\1|jquery.*\.js())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

> preg_match — Perform a regular expression match

```
if (preg_match("/jquery.*\.js/",$string)) {
    echo "Match found";
}
```

If it finds a match it will print out `Match found`. (I just used one of your regex strings)

I'm also assuming that `$string` is what you extracted, because it was hard to tell.

[Try it out](https://eval.in/780890)

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Comment: I think it's a problem with your regex string @TheDuck

Comment: Add `/` at the beginning and ending of his regular expression string.

Comment: My string contains: $subject = "jquery-3.2.0.min.js";

Comment: @TheDuck I mean this: "jquery(?:\-|\.)([\d.]\d)[^/]\.js\;version:\1"

Comment: @NoahCristino Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']' in

Comment: Here is my code: `if (preg_match("/jquery(?:\-|\.)([\d.]\d)[^/]\.js\;version:\1/", "jquery-3.2.0.min.js")) {
    echo "Match found";
}`

Comment: @TheDuck My code checks the regex, your regex string is just wrong

Comment: @TheDuck Check it now, I used a different regex pattern

Answer (score 3):

You can easily select script tags that are only links to the jquery lib using xpath:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xp->query('//script[.=""]/@src[contains(., "jquery")]');
foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

[demo](https://eval.in/780889)

Comment: Nice solution using  `DOMXPath`